# Google Appscript - Post info from a sheet to a Google Community?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-plus

Is there a way to write an appscript (inside the sheet) that posts info (in this case, statistics) to a Google Community? I have found an API script for something [similar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/plus-domains#creating_a_post):

```
function createPost() {
  var userId = 'me';
  var post = {
    object: {
      originalContent : 'Happy Monday! #caseofthemondays'
    },
    access: {
      items: [{
        type: 'domain'
      }],
      domainRestricted: true
    }
  };

  post = PlusDomains.Activities.insert(post, userId);
  Logger.log('Post created with URL: %s', post.url);
}
```

But how would I go about pointing that to a specific google community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned at topmost of your given [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/plus-domains#top_of_page), the Google+ Domains service allows you to use the [Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) in Apps Script.

With the use of Google+ Domains API, you can set restrictions to your posts or give [access control](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/acl) to one or more of the following audiences:

- Domain
- Extended Circles
- My Circles
- Circle
- Person

When sharing an activity, a user can specify the desired audience such as an individual person or one of their circles. When calling the Google+ Domains API, this audience is specified using the access property. For example, the following activity is being shared with a circle:

```
{
  /* ... */
  "access": {
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "circle", "id": "5678"
      }
    ],
    "domainRestricted": true
  }
}
```

To successfully implement this, you should also add members of that particular circle by using [Circles: addPeople](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/addPeople). With proper authorization and scopes, you can send a request using the following sample format:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/circles/circleId/people
```

Please try going through the given documentations for more information and other options like sharing to multiple audiences.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. As far as I can tell, you can't specifically share it with a Google community, right? So it's made me curious about how some scheduling software handles it. Was hoping maybe someone here would be able to point me in that direction.

Comment: Has the ability to specify a community been added in the last year?